# how to get value of variable from servlet class to the main.class?

Tags: java, class, servlets

i have two classes in one package **Servlet.class** and **Main.class**. I am trying to pass values that I get from servlet request to the main method. 

this is servlet code:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    response.setContentType("tesxt/plain");

    out.write(request.getParameter("code"));
    out.write("\n");
    out.write(request.getParameter("date"));

    Schedule_code sch = new Schedule_code();
    sch.setKod(request.getParameter("code"));
    out.write("\n" + "from class - " + sch.getKod());


    // out.close();

}
```

i want to get **Code** and **Date** values in main method to do some operations

Main.class

```
public class GetFromService {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String url1 = "http://192.168.1.9/udr/IhdMeta/ihd_rn.asmx/GetDescriptionIndexByCod?
sheduleCod="
            + schedule_cod + "&date=" + date;
    URL obj1 = new URL(url1);
    HttpURLConnection con1 = (HttpURLConnection) obj1.openConnection();
    con1.setRequestMethod("GET");
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean `I want to get values in main method`? If it's an actual `main`, then you actually shouldn't want to do that ever. Refactor your program so that the part which wants values is its own separate method.

Comment: Could we see the Main class? It would help to understand the context of Main.

Comment: @GorazdRebolj i have added **Main.class**

Comment: @M.Prokhorov i have added Main.class, so may be after that it would be clear for you*

Comment: @Marks, that's exactly what I was talking about. Just make a new method.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov can you explain it in detail please?

Comment: @Marks, make a new method that accepts `code` and `date` as parameters. Call that method from inside `main` and from inside `doGet`. In the method, do whatever you need with those parameters and return whatever you need to return.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov sorry, i am new to java, could you give an example of it, like where should i create method and etc. thank you

Comment: @Marks, generally speaking, wherever you feel like that lets your program compile and run successfully. Make it work first, then think about making it "beautiful".

Comment: @M.Prokhorov i have no idea how to do it, sorry. If you could show how to that with code...